# Browser back button does not work for Anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the footer of my page there a few links that point to different sections on the same page using anchor tags (# appended to the URL of the page).

This works fine, just the browser back button does not work: I cannot move back to the previous page from where I had navigated to the anchored page.

The simple question here is, is it possible to move back to previous page after navigating in the anchored page a few times? If it is then please could you suggest how?

Anchored page: the page that has several sections marked by the id attribute that can be pointed to by a URL with `#anchorId` at the end.

Comment: This is how it is _supposed_ to work, and does in all browsers by default. Users know and expect this behavior, so why mess with that?

Comment: Sounds good. Expected that to be default behaviour.It was raised as a defect in my project by QA.Can you please give a reference to any standard document available over internet that supports this default behaviour.

Comment: "It was raised as a defect in my project by QA". Oh wow.

Comment: @sebnukem sounds funny..but that's truth

Comment: I found a site that does what you're looking for. Credit goes to him, not me. Refer to the edited answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same problem see my question [anchor links referring to the page sections not working on browser refresh, back and forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125510/anchor-links-referring-to-the-page-sections-not-working-on-browser-refresh-back)

But I had to do it the way normal links work so what I did was I manually go to that section by getting the element from the hash.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () 
{
    var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
    $(window).scrollTop(top);
});
```

This works for forward and back buttons. 
And for refresh also you need to do the same thing. Get the element from the hash and scroll to that element manually.

Answer (score 1):

## History and the Back Button.

In days of old, the back button did little more that go to the previous item in the browser's history. That's changed quite a bit since then, as it keeps its own history according to a somewhat simple set of rules. Good luck digging through standards docs to find it though.

### UI/UX and why NOT to change expected behaviors.

Please reference [w3c's 'don't brek the back-button](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback) before you go making changes to a browser's default behavior. Its like that for a reason, following mountains of debate and defining standards.

Ultimately, this is what browsers do, and so this is what the users expect. If you begin to subvert the behavior away from user's expectations, you're likely to start pissing off your users. When buttons and links repeatedly **don't** behave as expected, users will often just give up and leave your site.

### Prevent Default.

If you *really* must alter the default behavior, the using javascript would be the best way to do it:

```
<a href="#id" onclick="return gotoAnchor(this);">

<script>
function gotoAnchor(elm) {
    window.event.returnValue = false;
    var url = location.href;

    location.href = elm.href;
    history.replaceState(null,null,url);

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `if you begin to subvert the behavior away from user's expectations, you're likely to start pissing off your users`.  See, that's the thing, I've yet to encounter a single user who *doesn't* expect the back button to take them to a previous anchor tag, as that's in the browsers history. It's inconsistent behavior that doesn't fit in with the majority of users day-to-day experiance

Comment: @DouglasGaskell, OP didn't give us enough information to understand the UX. Depending on what is actually happening, it _might_ be a good idea to change the behavior. However, anchors should _not_ be used to hide/show content, instead just focusing the scroll. The real question is, "what kind of action belongs in history?" New content: Yes. Scroll: No. An anchor is just a scroll (unless you're misusing it)

Comment: Fair enough. When I made that comment I was dealing with a very large SPA glossary of sorts with interlinking definitions and items. One of the requests was that users can follow anchor links to other definitions, and go back via the browser back button.

Comment: @Douglas Gaskell  I  agree. When I click something and the screen changes and  then click the back-button, I would expect the display to change back to what it was before.  IF somebody truly expects that NOTHING should happen when they click back-button in this situation,  they would not click it.  And  thus they would have no problem either.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/remove-anchor-links/

Visit that site. Scroll to the bottom and use test the anchors. It's doing what you want.

"The following code will parse your HTML page and override the function of any links that target anchor points on the same page. The link function will be replaced with a call to the  scrollIntoView method of the target element:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
  for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if(!links[i].hash) continue;
    if(links[i].origin + links[i].pathname != self.location.href) continue;
    (function(anchorPoint) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        anchorPoint.scrollIntoView(true);
        e.preventDefault();
      }, false);
    })(document.getElementById(links[i].hash.replace(/#/, "")));
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: That will prevent the browser from jumping to that section of the page in the first place … if you cancel the event, you have to “re-implement” jumping to that part of the page yourself, f.e. by using `scrollIntoView` method.

Comment: The above code was written to make anchor link that points to other section than top of the page to work.As on clicking the link it used to take to top of the page always ..however it would take to the designated section on clicking again

Comment: it would work for movements in the same page..but I doubt it would work for link pointing to another page section.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.referrer == "") {
window.open("index.php");
} else {
    window.history.go(-1);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add a quick explanation of the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery and without having to modify every anchor elements:

```
<script>
    // Makes sure we jump to anchor on reload
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        ele.scrollIntoView();
    });

    // Makes sure we jump to anchor when doing back and forward
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
        var ele = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        ele.scrollIntoView();
    }, false);
</script>
```