# anchor links referring to the page sections not working on browser refresh, back and forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have made a html page with links inside the page.

```
<div>
<a href="#first">first</a>
<a href="#second">second</a>
<div id="first">First div</div>
<div id="second">Second div</div>
</div>
```

But this code doesn't work on page refresh and browser back and forward buttons. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem. I am not looking for history api of html5 and history plugin of jquery. Want to create this in its basic format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have found out how to do it after a lot of attempts. Right now this handles my purpose so I am going ahead with this solution.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () 
{
    var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
    $(window).scrollTop(top);
});
```

This works for forward and back buttons. And for refresh also we need to do the same thing. Get the element from the hash and scroll to that element manually.