# Go back to index.php/about from extern site

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a one-page site with 3 other sites href="other.html" you can see it in the navbar. In the dropdown from the navbar, you can see that there are "extern" sites.
When I'm on one of that "extern" site and I want to go back to "index.php#about" how can I make that. So the thing is, that when the user on the "extern" site clicks on about that it jump to index.php#about and not only to index.php

Thx

```
       <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar" id="navspy">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top" data-scroll>AR PhotoArt</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler first-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto smooth-scroll">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about" data-scroll>LebensArt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#studio" data-scroll>ArbeitsArt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio" data-scroll>LichtArt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-scroll-ignore>
          Mehr
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="other1.html">Anleitung</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="other2.html">Wettbewerb</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="other3.html">Kurs</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#kontakt" data-scroll>Kontakt</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about back, forward, and refresh functionality in the browser.

I have included one possible solution in jQuery (not sure if you are using jQuery tho)

Also, took the javascript solution from the SO answer below ....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046922/791600

---

***UPDATE***

So with the jQuery code that you said needs to be offset by 49, here is what you want to do with that:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () 
{
    var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
    top += 49;
    $(window).scrollTop(top);
});
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () 
{
    var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
    $(window).scrollTop(top);
});
```

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
  for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if(!links[i].hash) continue;
    if(links[i].origin + links[i].pathname != self.location.href) continue;
    (function(anchorPoint) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        anchorPoint.scrollIntoView(true);
        e.preventDefault();
      }, false);
    })(document.getElementById(links[i].hash.replace(/#/, "")));
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: this works very good
only thing: i put a offset(49) but the offset doesn't work...

Comment: if you need to adjust the offset, just adjust the value of "top" after it calculates the position.  (so  `top += 49` or `top -= 49`)

Comment: @UdisKlorenz Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if this answer worked for you.   Thanks :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I tried what you said with the offset but it doesn't work...
other ideas?

Comment: @UdisKlorenz so are you getting it to work but it's 49 pixels off or something??  can you post the code that you are trying to use in your question please?

Comment: `$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
              var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top+=49;
              $(window).scrollTop(top);
          });`

or `$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
              var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
              $(window).scrollTop(top+=49);
          });`

I tried both variants.

look the image so you can see that the title is under the navbar.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1667bb5vQ8MFKGV5ApCdK7KNGRcC0z3o2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @UdisKlorenz Please see the UPDATE I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add slash `/index.php` in url before you filename.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/index.php#about" data-scroll>LebensArt</a>
```

And this link edit like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/other1.html">Anleitung</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/other2.html">Wettbewerb</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/other3.html">Kurs</a>
```